# Unable to reinstall MySQL after mistakenly installing MariaDB

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, mysql, mariadb

I did not realize that installing MariaDB would overwrite so much of MySQL, and make it unusable--I didn't know they were so similar.

I'd prefer to stay with MySQL, but when attempting to fix my mistake I'm having issues installing MySQL again.

I've already copied my /var/lib/msql folder to safe location, and attempted to purge all MariaDB and MySQL packages, but I'm getting the following failure when I attempt to reinstall:

```
root@homeserver:/home/ryan# apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libhtml-template-perl libmecab2 mecab-ipadic mecab-ipadic-utf8 mecab-utils mysql-server-8.0 mysql-server-core-8.0
Suggested packages:
  libipc-sharedcache-perl mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libhtml-template-perl libmecab2 mecab-ipadic mecab-ipadic-utf8 mecab-utils mysql-server mysql-server-8.0 mysql-server-core-8.0
0 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/25.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 179 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package libaio1:amd64.
(Reading database ... 240010 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-libaio1_0.3.112-5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libaio1:amd64 (0.3.112-5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmecab2:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../1-libmecab2_0.996-6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmecab2:amd64 (0.996-6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-core-8.0.
Preparing to unpack .../2-mysql-server-core-8.0_8.0.18-0ubuntu0.19.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-core-8.0 (8.0.18-0ubuntu0.19.10.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../3-mysql-server-8.0_8.0.18-0ubuntu0.19.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
invoke-rc.d returned 5
There is a MySQL server running, but we failed in our attempts to stop it.
Stop it yourself and try again!
```

When I attempt to stop MySQL, it says it isn't running.

Any ideas?

This is Ubuntu 19.04.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer elsewhere:

Use:

```
dpkg -P | grep mysql 
dpkg -P | grep mariadb
```

This will find all the installed packages. I uninstalled all of them with:

```
dpkg -P package-name
```

Then rebooted.